# Jquery, Codeigniter 2.1 - pagination issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am creating pagination using Codeigniter, and I want to add ajax functionality. JS is working when pagination link is clicked first time. When it is clicked for the second time JS doesn't work and pagination is working via PHP controller (this part is working without any problem). This is JS code:

```
var pag = $('#pagination a');

    pag.on('click', function(e){
        var pagination =
            {
            target : $(this).attr('href') + ' .mali_oglasi',    
            content : $('.mali_oglasi'),
            container: $('.mali_oglasi_wrapper')
            };

            pagination.content.animate({'opacity':0, scrollTop: 0}, 400, function(){
                pagination.container.load(pagination.target, function(){
                    pagination.content.animate({'opacity':1}, 400);
                });                
            });            
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
```

Also **scrollTop** doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let me guess: `#pagination a` is in the part that's reloaded, right?

Comment: Well yes, and it seems to be a problem as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably that's because your DOM gets manipulated everytime, and hence the handler for the click event is lost.

try this way :

```
$('body').on('click', '#pagination a', function(e) {
    var pagination =
    {
        target : $(this).attr('href') + ' .mali_oglasi',    
        content : $('.mali_oglasi'),
        container: $('.mali_oglasi_wrapper')
    };

    pagination.content.animate({
        'opacity':0, 
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 400, function(){
        pagination.container.load(pagination.target, function(){
            pagination.content.animate({
                'opacity':1
            }, 400);
        });                
    });            
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

this will ensure rebinding the click event on each DOM manipulation

Comment: That is exactly what I need :). scrollTop still doesn't work, I guess I need to put it somewhere else. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

try this bro..

maybe the element was not yet loaded...

> var pag = $('#pagination a');
>
> ```
> pag.on('click', 'a', function(e){
>     var pagination =
>         {
>         target : $(this).attr('href') + ' .mali_oglasi',    
>         content : $('.mali_oglasi'),
>         container: $('.mali_oglasi_wrapper')
>         };
>
>         pagination.content.animate({'opacity':0, scrollTop: 0}, 400, function(){
>             pagination.container.load(pagination.target, function(){
>                 pagination.content.animate({'opacity':1}, 400);
>             });                
>         });            
>     e.preventDefault(); 
> });
> ```

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated and no more in stock as of jQuery 1.8